# How to get gstreamer pipeline's topology (diagram)

Tags: c, gstreamer

I am trying to get pipeline topology but when I create it I use [gst_pipeline_new](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstpipeline.html#gst_pipeline_new)
which returns a GstElement, on the other hand GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE expects a GstBin
[GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/debugutils.html#gst_debug_bin_to_dot_file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gst_pipeline_new()` returns a `GstPipeline*`, a subclass of `GstBin` which is a subclass of `GstElement`. The reason it returns a `GstElement*` is just because most people usually call `GstElement` methods on it afterwards, and since C doesn't support polymorphism, you have to cast.

This brings us to the answer for your question: `GstPipeline` is just a subclass of `GstBin`, so you can just cast the type using usual C casts (e.g. `(GstBin *) pipeline`) or using the GObject casting macros (which do a runtime type check (e.g. `GST_BIN (pipeline)`)